# I am currently learning react and I ran into error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ubuntu

[I have tried everything but idk why is this happening. please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ7t3.png)

Comment: `props.dish`, `props.promotion` or `props.leader` is `undefined`, which means that no value is given for one or more of these properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question description didn't have property 'image',
But I guess you follow this can be sol:

```
import image from './yourImageName.png'; // Tell webpack this JS file uses this image
```

.png can replace as .jpg ... whatever you want. It's your file extension.

You can read [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) to a more clear concept